# Netsuite apply credit memo to invoice using Suitetalk rest api

Tags: netsuite-rest-api

I'm trying to apply credit memo to invoice using Suitetalk but there is no available field for "apply" in suitetalk api browser.

Below is the link of Netsuite's REST API browser that I am using
https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/APIs/REST_API_Browser/record/v1/2023.1/index.html

I tried using POST/PATCH request with creditMemo object for payload

Comment: I facing the same issue, I've contacted some vendors, and it seems the feature is not ready yet to apply CM using API

Answer (score 0):

To apply an creditMemo to an invoice transaction in NetSuite using the REST API, the request url can be formatted like:

```
POST .../services/rest/record/v1/invoice/{invoiceId}/!transform/creditMemo
```

From what I can tell, this creates a credit memo from the invoice, but also associates the original invoice with it.

Comment: Just a thing to know, I spent days on it, the body apparently has to be empty.